# How to replace unicode in emacs?

Tags: replace, unicode, align

I'm using spacemacs, and am wondering how you do certain commands like replace and align with respect to unicode (particularly relevant for Agda development).

For instance, `→` has the `\to` shortcut in insert mode, but `%s/→/->/g` isn't doable with the same unicode shortcuts. This is also the case with align-by-regex, for example.

However, one can search for unicode. Is there some way to explicity paste unicode in these meta commands, or is this something I can edit in my `.spacemacs`?

Comment: Try `C-x 8 RET`: that allows you to enter Unicode interactively in various ways. It's bound to `insert-char`, so do `C-h f insert-char` for more details.

Comment: The question is not specific enough: *"how you do certain commands like replace and align"*. Replacing is not aligning. Please limit each question to one specific question.

Comment: Using `C-x 8 RET` within Query replace seems to start to work, but with OP's `\to` example, gives an "invalid character" error.  I imagine there's another way to enter the same Unicode character, but it doesn't work for the original question with Query replace.